# Disable speak Now prompt in Voice Recognition in Android

Tags: voice-recognition

When i click on Voice Search in android it gives a pop up screen SPEAK NOW and after i speak say Hello then a WORKING screen comes.
Can i know how to disable the default Speak Now and Working screen in Voice Recognition in Android.

These screens are displayed as i use the API RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH.

How can i give my screens and know where actual processing takes place?

Comment: Anyone worked on Voice Recognition using Google Voice Search???

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the user has solved their problem by now. For anyone seeing this today, the answer is to use the `SpeechRecognizer` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

The `SpeechRecognizer` lets you use speech recognition from within your own Activity, defining custom UI.